# Connect external MQTT docker container with springboot docker-compose file

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, mqtt, message-queue

I have a Springboot application with mysql database and now I want to connect to an external MQTT broker.

Following are my configs:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
 foo:
  name: foo
  driver: bridge

services:
  app-server:
  build: .
  container_name: Player1
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  restart: always
  networks:
   - foo
  depends_on: 
   - mydb
external_links:
  - mosquitto:eclipse-mosquitto
environment:
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mydb:3306/takeaway_db?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

mydb:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  restart: always
  networks:
   - foo
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root 
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssword1234
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
```

and **Dockerfile**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=target/spring-boot-web.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

**application.properties**

```
mqtt.borker.url=tcp://172.18.0.2:1883 #container ip address from container inspect
mqtt.borker.username=username
mqtt.borker.password=password
```

command for starting MQTT broker

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 --net foo --name mosquitto eclipse-mosquitto
```

When I run docker-compose up, I get the followig error:

```
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable to connect to server
................
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Why are you using ip addresses when you can use container names when everything is on the same docker network? e.g. `eclipse-mosquitto` since you've got an `external_links` section

Comment: yes, you are right. changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the idea behind this solution should apply to connect any docker-compose containers with any other external containers.

1. Create or add existing containers to a network.

   ```
   docker network create foo 

   docker run -it -d -p 1883:1883 --net foo --name mosquitto eclipse-mosquitto
   ```
2. Update docker compose file.

   a. Add network foo to the containers.

   b. Connect/expose network foo in compose file to the external network foo.

   c. Link app container to the external container.

   ```
    version: '3.5'

    services:
     app-server:
      build: .
      container_name: ...
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - foo               // =========> (a)
      depends_on: 
        - mydb
      external_links:
        - mosquitto:eclipse-mosquitto  //============> (c)

     mydb:
      image: mysql
      container_name: ...
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      restart: always
      networks:
        - foo              // =========> (a)

    networks:
       foo:
         external:
           name: foo // ========> (b)
   ```

The complete docker file can be found [here](https://github.com/shibasish/GameOfThree/blob/master/docker-compose-p1.yml).

3. Update links in the `application.properties` file.

   ```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mydb:3306/takeaway_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

    mqtt.borker.url=tcp://mosquitto:1883
   ```